# Setting the timeout of a HAPI FHIR IGenericClient

Tags: dstu2-fhir, hl7-fhir, hapi-fhir

I'm trying to run a fhir search using the following code;

```
FhirContext ctx = FhirContext.forDstu2();
ctx.getRestfulClientFactory().setConnectTimeout(2000000);
IGenericClient client = ctx.newRestfulGenericClient("http://localhost:1080/hapi-fhir-jpaserver-example/baseDstu2");

Bundle results = client.search().forResource(Basic.class).returnBundle(ca.uhn.fhir.model.dstu2.resource.Bundle.class).execute();
```

However when it runs, it always throws the exception 'FhirClientConnectionException' which is caused by the exception 'SocketTimeoutException'.  Am I to assume that this is the server timing out, and not my local connection, since I set my local to 2000000?

How do I go about fixing thing?  I'm using HAPI in it's out of the box config, and it times out searching through a relatively small amount of resources within about 10-15 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

Try `setSocketTimeout()` instead.

Like this:

```java
FhirContext ctx = FhirContext.forDstu2();
ctx.getRestfulClientFactory().setSocketTimeout(200 * 1000);
IGenericClient client = ctx.newRestfulGenericClient("http://localhost:1080/hapi-fhir-jpaserver-example/baseDstu2");

Bundle results = client.search().forResource(Basic.class).returnBundle(ca.uhn.fhir.model.dstu2.resource.Bundle.class).execute();
```

v3 example:

```java
serverBase =  "http://hapi.fhir.org/baseDstu3";
ctx = FhirContext.forDstu3();
ctx.getRestfulClientFactory().setSocketTimeout(200 * 1000);

// Create the client
client = ctx.newRestfulGenericClient(serverBase);
```

I found the answer reading source code here: https://github.com/jamesagnew/hapi-fhir/blob/master/hapi-fhir-jpaserver-base/src/test/java/ca/uhn/fhir/jpa/provider/dstu3/ResourceProviderDstu3Test.java#L1710